# Display twitter feeds

Tags: twitter

For an event in a couple of weeks I'd like to make an web page/app which display tweets from a specific user, a specific hashtag and all @reply's at the first user in 3 boxes on the screen.

However I've never tried this. I want to use either .NET (C#) or HTML/CSS/JS since I'm proficient in those. Are there any libraries/API's I can use? Or is there an readily available freeware/open-source app I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: That link returns: "The Page Could Not Be Found". Use either of the following [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.com/) OR [NuGet Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetSharp)

Answer (score 0):

Use Twitter's [profile](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile) and [search](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_search) widgets. Profile for the first box, a search of the hash tag for the second box, and a search of `to:username` for the third box.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just posted this as an answer to another question:

I just updated a [plugin](http://zkniebel.github.com/jquery-twitter-feed/) to work with the Twitter 1.1 API. Unfortunately, per Twitter's urging, you will have to perform the actual request from server-side code. However, you can pass the response to the plugin and it will take care of the rest. I don't know what framework you are running, but I have already added sample code for making the request in C#, and will be adding sample code for PHP, shortly.

The plugin makes a call to `statuses/user_timeline`, but you will likely want to look at `statuses/filter` or `statuses/search`, instead. All you will have to do is add your desired parameters (hashtag, replies, etc.) to the server-side code and it should work (with the addition of your security keys and tokens, of course).

Good luck! :)